# mvc3 how to bind a view using HttPost

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

This is my first post,I am just getting my feet wet with mvc3.I have a form with 3 models in a view and I am trying to submit the form yet the 3 fields that I have come out to null once submitted in the database; this is the form. How the models are created : The main one is **countries** which is the one I have a problem submitting because it comes out to null

```
  public class countries
{
    public string china { get; set; }
    public string japan { get; set; }
    public string thailand { get; set; }
   }
  // I know put multiple models inside allmyplanets
    public class allmyplanets
     {
          public IEnumerable<politcal> rankworld { get; set; }
    public countries asia { get; set; }
     public president names { get; set; }
        }
```

This is how the view looks, the form is only for countries the one im trying to submit

```
John.Models.allmyplanets


   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("planet", "earth", null, new AjaxOptions
{
UpdateTargetId = "submitted",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
HttpMethod = "POST"
 }))
{
 @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.asia.china)
 @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.asia.japan)
  @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.asia.thailand)

        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="myform" id="submitform" value="Submit Form" />
}
```

Thats the simple form with 3 fields now on submit I tried to capture the value and it does form a new row in the database but all 3 fields come out to null this is how i try to capture it...

```
 public PartialViewResult planet(countries submit,string asia_china, string asia_japan, string asia_thailand)
    {
        submit.china = asia_china;
        submit.japan = asia_japan;
        submit.thailand = asia_thailand;
        db.countries.Add(submit);
        db.SaveChanges();
  }
```

what can be wrong with the code that causes everything to be null? I put the under-dash because razor naming convention turns all ID's with multiple multiples to under-dashes to separate such as id="asia_china". How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult planet(allmyplanets allplanet)
{
    countries country=new countries();
    allplanet.asia=country;
    //save the data         
}
```